# Beanstalk: how to handle Multiple jobs per second (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, message-queue, beanstalkd

I need to send thousands of emails and sms to users every day at 8:00 AM, for which i'm using Beanstalk hosted on EC2 to process asynchronously. Currently it's taking almost 15 minutes to process 1000 jobs and i have 4 processes. Even if i increase number of processes in supervisor, its not decreasing the processing time of 1000 jobs.

I found the same issue posted on laravel forum but no one replied,

http://laravel.io/forum/02-09-2014-run-multiple-queue-jobs-the-same-time-with-beanstalk-and-supervisor

Can someone please guide.

Comment: How many EC2 instances do you use for sending emails?

Comment: its only one instance.

Comment: If you want to decrease the processing time you have to start more instances. Because I think you reach the performance limit on your servers.